# Table is forcing width of div in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

We have a page similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
          content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>Welcome to Application</title>
        <style type="text/css">
html, body, div, table, tr, th, td {
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
    font-size: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #036;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

* html body {
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    display: block;
    margin: 18px auto 0;
    width: 750px;
}

* html .container {
    height: 1%;
    text-align: left;
}

.container:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.section {
    border-color: #e5e5e5 #dbdbdb #d2d2d2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    padding: 17px 39px;
}

table, th, td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

th, td {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 9px;
    text-align: left;
}

table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1.4em;
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    background: #c3d9ff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: smaller;
    font-weight: 700;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section">
                <table cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Header</th>
                        <th>Header</th>
                        <th>Header</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>d</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>e</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>f</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `div` displays correctly in Chrome and Firefox 3.6 on Windows XP, but, when viewed in IE6, the `table` is forcing the `div` to be wider than the specified 750 pixels.

This issue has now been partially resolved by explicitly setting the width of the table to 670 pixels

We'd still prefer a resolution where the width of the table doesn't need to be explicitly defined

Comment: This is working for me in IE6 - is it when you add content that the div width is increased?

Comment: @lnrbob, if I load the above markup in Chrome and IE6 and compare the two widths, the widths are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have IE6 on my computer, though I tried the simulator at http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ and one thing that seemed to work (short of explicitly setting a 670px width on `.container` or `table`) was to add the following:

```
* html .section{
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm guessing that tells IE6 that `table`'s setting of `width: 100%;` should be based on `.section`'s computed width (which is affected by its padding and border) instead of `.container`'s width of 750px.